# Is this an acceptable oil filler cap?

Tags: oil, parts

So got a replacement engine oil filler cap from
Honda using my reg.

This new cap does not have the original English writing which specified oil type  but more importantly does not turn all the way down like the original did.  From the pic you can see there is a big gap of visible cap thread.  It’s already too tight.  Was thinking of using pliers to undo it but this might leave marks making difficult to get refund.

Are replacement caps meant to fit like this, acceptable to use and do u have any ideas how I can move it?

Thanks
[image]

[image]

Comment: If it has "710" then it is a cheap copy…

Comment: @SolarMike That is obviously OIL upside down!

Comment: @alephzero yup, that's the joke... normally a blonde - told it to my sister who is blonde and she found it funny then told me another...

Comment: Go back, get them to remove it and supply the correct one.

Comment: It might or might not be the correct oil filler cap, but why have you put it on top of one of the front suspension mounts, and not where it belongs, which is on top of the engine? See https://www.carthrottle.com/post/n445xpp/ for example.

Comment: @alephzero I am trying to understand what your comment is about.  Are you saying that the the red thing in the OP’s photo is not an engine?

Comment: @HandyHowie It took me a little while thinking the OP's pictures looked strange before the penny dropped and I thought "Since when did oil filler caps screw into something painted like bodywork?" Look at the picture in my comment link (not exactly the same engine, but a similar Honda Civic).. The "red thing" matches top of the suspension mount on the right hand side painted in the body color. Notice the identical two pipes/hoses behind the mount, in both my picture and the OP's. The oil filler cap (identical to the OP's) is on the unpainted camshaft cover, where you would expect it to be.

Comment: @alephzero Pretty sure it is this VTEC engine, you can see the same pipe and the nut  in the OP’s photo - https://www.spinny.com/blog/index.php/honda-i-vtec-petrol-engines-everything-you-need-to-know/

Comment: @HandyHowie Malwarebytes blocked your link to spinny.com.

Comment: @alephzero If you do a google image search for “Honda vtec engine” you will see lots of red Honda engines that look like the OP’s

Comment: @HandyHowie Fair enough, but more than half of the 6th generation models of civics did *not* have VTEC engines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It clearly isn’t the correct one for your engine.  Either the threads are the wrong size or the threaded part is too long.  Air could be leaking past the threads, so a better fitting one is needed.

If you are saying that it is now stuck in, then if you put a thick cloth over the cap and use something like these, you should be able to get it out without damaging it.  Put the jaws in vertically from above.

[image]

I got this photo from - https://terrybookers.co.uk/large-water-pump-pliers-1658-p.asp