# Can I use the wrong engine oil filler cap?

Tags: oil, parts

Honda Civic vti coupe 1999.

I recently asked this question as I bought an oil filler cap from Honda that didn’t fit.
[Is this an acceptable oil filler cap?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/85456/is-this-an-acceptable-oil-filler-cap)

Honda have just told me they no longer provide the original part for this car and Instead use a superseded part which is the one they have sent and if it doesn’t fit tough and I’d have to go to a breakers etc to source the original as they no longer make it.  They also said because I forced it they will unlikely refund it however may do if I can remove it without any damage.

Gonna try remove it safely as was suggested in another answer but I have to drive to garage to get it removed so will effectively be used.

As such I’m thinking I may as well use it until I source a replacement.  I’m thinking I should just tighten it reasonably and cello tape the edges so no air gets sucked in?  Would that be an acceptable and effective way to use the part until replaced?  If I don’t mind repeat cellotaping can I just use the part as mentioned indefinitely? I imagine air getting in is the only real issue but taping over can prevent that? Even if the cello tape will dissolve from heat will the little amount of air going in cause an issue - I imagine not much dust will be going in which is the real issue?

Really don’t like the idea of paying for another filler cap assuming this one won’t be refunded.

On another note can I say anything to Honda?  If they superseded the part and it didn’t fit they should not have sold it but I guess they will still argue I shouldn’t have used/forced it in.

Thanks
[image: as you can see in pic filler cap does not go all the way in]

Comment: You should not have forced it - any one with mechanical feeling can, and does, feel the threads starting to bind and stops.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure this is not the right cap?  It looks to me a bit like it's cross-threaded.  You might remove it and look at the threads on the cap vs. the filler hole.  I find it quite unlikely that Honda would have mistakenly listed this cap as the correct PN for your engine when it doesn't actually fit.

Comment: What specific part numbers are you dealing with here for the oil cap?

Comment: @jwh20  Honda U.K. have told me the original part number for my car 15610-pd1-000.  The new superceding U.K. part they sent has ynumber 15610-p2a-000.  And just for reference the original US number is 15610-p2e-a01

Comment: ...is what exactly?

Comment: @jwh20 u asked me what part numbers I am dealing with.  Like I said the cap they sent is 15610p2a000 which is a supercession of the original oil filler but doesn’t fit as per pic. As it didn’t fit they told me to source the original from breakers saying the part number is 15610pd1000.  This are U.K. numbers.  The third number is the American number - not sure if it’s for original or superceded.

Comment: A google search for "Honda part 15610-pd1-000" gave the first hit as a UK parts supplier who stated this was an obsolete part with limited supply, showed a picture that is different from the filler cap you can't fit, and quoted a price and delivery time. Of course it would be worth checking before parting with any money but "obsolete" doesn't mean "unobtainable" - it just means *Honda* don't supply it any more.

Answer (score 1):

Since the threads aren't matching it is the wrong cap. Any jury-rigging with some sort of tape, stacked gaskets or any other "creative measures" will only make it worse. Get the right cap.

> Really don’t like the idea of paying for another filler cap assuming this one won’t be refunded.

What is the cost of a matching filler cap? A handful of money.
What is risk you are taking? A whole lot more. A car isn't an investment (excluding super-rare models in pristine state, not an 20y+ old honda). It costs money to drive it, and it costs money for upkeep. The only benefit is that it allows you to move around.

Perhaps you want to go over your questions about your car and try find out if you are really made for servicing motor vehicles, or if your strengths are somewhere else. Sometimes the resulting repair costs of the "fixes" exceed what an professional would have charged in the first run.

[Good read](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunk_cost#Fallacy_effect)